# Always On Instance Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport connection endpoint Error

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, mirroring, error-log

I have a production instance that has 2 AOG. There is no mirroring configured for both groups. Both groups are also in 'Healthy' state.

Upon checking the error log on SQL Server, I noticed that starting from 12/19/20 there has been this error that started at 9:03PM. I went through an dug in further to see that there is a pattern. Every night around 9:03-9:04pm the same error is happening. This does not occur during normal business hours.

Error msg:

An error occurred in a Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport connection endpoint, Error: 8474, State: 11. (Near endpoint role: Target, far endpoint address: '')`

My thought was to stop and restart the endpoints, but I don't think that would be necessary in this case.

Anyone have any thoughts as to why it might be happening on a daily basis around the same time, and how I may be able to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in place read-only routing?
Try to review read-only routing URL in the Availability Group Properties / Read-Only Routing.

Maybe the connection at that time is using this feature and the routing URL for the secondary is not right.

Eventually try to verify what encryption algorythm you are using.

```
SELECT name ,
type_desc ,
state_desc ,
role_desc ,
is_encryption_enabled ,
connection_auth_desc ,
encryption_algorithm_desc
FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints;
```

Usually AES. Veryfy if you are using the same algorythm in both node.

Comment: No the AOG is not using in place read only routing. I checked the AGO properties > Read-Only-Routing and the Read-Only-Routing URL column is blank. Is it a good practice to use this feature?

Comment: It requires EE license. If you have it and if you have application that execute read only workloads yes